# How to send form using hyperlink in Spring Form tag?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Actually my jsp have spring tags I'm sending form when hyperlink was clicked.

My Jsp page is simple Login page when user is forgot password when enter the username(email) and click `Forgot password?` mail will be send destination account.

Problem is when we are click `submit` button form will be sending but when I'm clicking `forgot password?` hyperlink form values not sending it show null.

Hear is my Jsp:

```
    <form:form action="login" modelAttribute="LOGIN">

    </form:form>
</fieldset>
<script>
    $('#LOGIN').ajaxForm({
        target : '#body',
        success : function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            alert(responseText);
        },
        beforeSubmit : function() {
            $.blockUI({
                message : '<h1> Just a moment...</h1>'
            });
        }
    });
    function submitUserName() {
        $('#LOGIN').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Actually in my jsp I'm writing onclick function but also not working...
Any mistake on my jsp code?

Please give me suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case hyperlink provide standard behavior, when you click **forgot password?** browser just followed by link. If you want submit username you should do something like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#resend_password_link").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault(); // interrupt default hyperlink behavior
                $("#LOGIN").attr("action",$(this).attr("href"));
                $("#LOGIN").submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add id attribute to this form tag - id="loginForm"

```
 <form:form action="login/processLogin" id="loginForm" modelAttribute="LOGIN">
```

And then inside your function submit this form using id

```
function submitUserName() {
    $('#loginForm').submit();
}
```

Put an alert (123); inside the function to see if it is coming up or not. If it is not coming up, you do have javascript issues on page load. you need to resolve them first.

I hope this will work.

Comment: @Deepak.. if you are giving modelAttribute it's treat as id.. so why we are using id?